# Showing $\cos(t^2)$ is not a Characteristic Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Usually when we try to show a function is not a characteristic function, we would prove it is not uniformly continuous. I am wondering if there is any other way to show $\cos(t^2)$ is not a characteristic function.
$%fooling edit check$

Comment: If we can show that $E(X^2)=0$, how does that imply $\phi$ is not a char fun? thanks but $$-\varphi^{\prime\prime}(t)|_{t=0}=0.$$ is true since $\phi''=2\sin(t^2)+4t^2 \cos(t^2)$

Comment: For a characteristic function $\varphi$, isn't the set of points $t$ with $\varphi(t)=1$ supposed to be contained in a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb R$ ?  But in this case, the group generated is dense.

Comment: show that it is not positive definite

Answer (score 13):

**Hint:** Put $\varphi(t)=\cos(t^2)$. 
If $X$ is a random variable with this "characteristic function", we'd have 
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=-\varphi^{\prime\prime}(t)|_{t=0}=0.$$

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I was looking for answers to this same question and I have a doubt with this argument. Couldn't it be that $X$ doesn't have a second order moment? [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793788/continuous-probability-distribution-with-no-first-moment-but-the-characteristic)

Comment: @Duronman All moments exist since $cos(t^2)$ is infinitely differentiable at 0.

Comment: How is E(X^2)=0 imply that X doesn't have a second moment? Isin't zero a finte value?

Answer (score 8):

Introduce the notation $c(t)=\cos(t^2)$. By Bochner's theorem, every determinant $D(t)$ should be nonnegative, where
$$
D(t)=\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}c(0) & c(t) & c(2t)\\ c(-t) & c(0) & c(t)\\ c(-2t) & c(-t) & c(0)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $c(t)=c(-t)$ for every $t$, $D(t)=(1-c(2t))E(t)$ with $E(t)=1-2\cos(t^2)^2+\cos(4t^2)$.
For $t=1$, $E(1)=1-2\cos(1)^2+\cos(4)=-0.24...$ hence $D(1)<0$.

Alternatively, $E(t)=-6t^4+O(t^8)$ when $t\to0$. Or, $E(t)=-2\sin^2(t^2)(1+2\cos(2t^2))$.