# Continuous probability distribution with no first moment but the characteristic function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I am looking for an example of a *continuous* distribution function where the first moment does not exist but the characteristic function is differentiable everywhere.

Cauchy distributions do not fulfill this, as their characteristic functions are not differentiable at $0$. Does anybody here have an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below, there is a discrete example because I misread the word continuous.

However, if $X$ has the density $f$ given by 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{ if }|x|\leqslant 2,\\
\frac C{x^2\log |x|}&\mbox{ if }|x|>2,\end{cases}$$
then $X$ is not integrable and the characteristic function is given by 
$$\varphi(t)=2C\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2\log x}\mathrm{d}x.$$

- Let us show that $\varphi$ is differentiable at $0$ and $\varphi'(0)=0$. We start from 
  $$\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(0)}{2tC}=\int_2^{1/t}\frac{\cos(tx)-1}{x^2\log x}\frac{dx}t+\int_{1/t}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)-1}{x^2\log x}\frac{dx}t=:A(t)+B(t).$$
  Then using $|\cos u-1|\leqslant u^2$
  $$|A(t)|\leqslant \int_2^{1/t}\frac{t^2x^2}{x^2\log x}\frac{dx}t=t\int_2^{1/t}\frac{dx}{\log x}.$$
  Let $y:=\log x$, then $x=e^y$ and $dx=e^ydy$:
  $$|A(t)|\leqslant t\int_{\log 2}^{-\log t}\frac{e^y}y\mathrm dy,$$
  and splitting the interval at $R$, we get 
  $$|A(t)|\leqslant te^R/\log 2+R^{-1},$$
  hence $\lim_{to\to 0}A(t)=0$. 
  Since 
  $$|B(t)|\leqslant \frac 1t\int_{1/t}^\infty\frac{2}{x^2\log(x)}dx,$$
  we obtain after the substitution $s=1/x$ that 
  $$|B(t)|\leqslant -\frac 2t\int_0^t\frac{ds}{\log s}.$$
  An other transformation $tu=s$ yields
  $$|B(t)|\leqslant -\int_0^1\frac{du}{\log u+\log t},$$
  which converges to $0$ as $t$ goes to $0$.
- A similar argument can be used to show the differentiability at each point.

This example is taken from Stoyanov's book *Counter-examples in probability*.

---

Take $X$ such that $$\mathbb P(X=(-1)^kk)=\frac C{k^2\log k},\quad k\geqslant 2.$$
Then $\mathbb E|X|$ is infinite, while the characteristic function
$$\varphi_X(t)=\sum_{k\geqslant 2}\frac C{k^2\log k}e^{it(-1)^kk}$$
is differentiable everywhere: compute $\varphi_X(t+h)-\varphi_X(t)$ approximating $e^{ih(-1)^kk}-1$ by $h(-1)^kk+o(h)$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo How did you treat the term containing the $\sin$?

Comment: You mean, in the computation of the characteristic function, don't you? The distribution is symmetric.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo but if this integral does not exist on each side, then we are calculating something like a Cauchy principal value not the integral itself, kind of similar to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x dx \neq 0$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo do you know what I mean?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo and no, I mean the computation of the characteristic function is clear, as the integrand is bounded by $\frac{1}{x^2}$, I am talking about the computation of the derivative of the characteristic function for $s=0$. In that case, I suspect problems with the imaginary part.

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what you did there: You start with an integral like $\frac{2}{t} \int_0^\infty \frac{|1-cos(tx)|}{x^2 \log(x)} dx$, and then you split and use $|1-cos(tx)|\le ...$ on both integrals. But what do you substitute then?

Comment: I've edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo thank you, but no it does not. For example I am still wondering why your $2$ from the distribution function disappeared and why your integration is from $0$ to $\infty$. I'm sorry that I don't get it.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I would also be interested in seeing a few more hints what you actually want to do there.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo are you willing to add a few Details?

Comment: Done now. ${}{}$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I'm not sure I understand your discrete example.  The $o(h)$ there also depends on $k$, and in fact it goes as $k^2$ I think.  And even the first term of your approximation is not summable in $k$.  I guess the whole point is that without first moment you're not supposed to be able to use convergence theorems, but if not, then what can we do?

Comment: @Jeff You are right. Probably we have to do a similar truncation as in the continuous case.