# Finite 1-order derivative of characteristic functions implies finite expectation?

Tags: probability

We know that if $f$ is the characteristic function of a distribution $\mu$, and $f$ has a finite derivative of even order $k$ at $t=0$, then $\mu$ has a finite moment of order k.

I want to find a counterexample of the condition when and $f$ has a finite derivative of order $1$, does it mean the $\mu$ has a finite moment of order $1$ (finite expectation)?

Comment: Are you looking for a counterexample to $\mathbb{E}\left[ X\right] = -i\, f_X^\prime(0)$ where the right hand side is finite?

Comment: @Henry Yes. When the LHS is finite this is true, but when we only know the RHS is finite can we conclude that $E[X]$ is finite?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative. You may need additional hypothesis. There's a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793788/continuous-probability-distribution-with-no-first-moment-but-the-characteristic).